# how to join two array is scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

suppose I have two arrays

```
val x =Array("one","two","three")
val y =Array("1","2","3")
```

what's the most elegant way to get a new array like 
["one1","two2","three3"]

Comment: yes ,it's very helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `zip` and `map` should do it:

```
(x zip y) map { case (a, b) => a + b }
```

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to @m-z, with a for comprehension, like this,

```
for ( (a,b) <- x zip y ) yield a + b
```

This can be encapsulated into an implicit such as

```
implicit class StrArrayOps(val x: Array[String]) extends AnyVal { 
  def join(y: Array[String]) = 
    for ( (a,b) <- x zip y ) yield a + b 
}
```

and use it like this,

```
x join y
Array(one1, two2, three3)
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to `zip`:

```
(0 until math.min(x.length, y.length))
          .map(i => x(i) + y(i))
          .toArray
```